# Bypassing string array as a parameters and using dynamic query in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing

I working in PostgreSQL past years, but i had no idea about array concept and how to handle array in PostgreSQL. i need a dynamic query for selecting columns in multiple table and the result will be in cursor, columns names should be dynamically will change.

for e.g (in a multiple table totally 30 columns is there If user need col1, col5,col6,col25), so select statement query will be dynamically will change like:

```
select col1, col5,col6,col25 from table ....
```

another user need col2,col5,col7,col29,col26, select statement will change dynamically as

```
select col2,col5,col7,col29,col26 from table .... and so on.
```

stored procedure passing parameters will be array

```
create or replace function func_my_method(check_in character varying, sel character varying[])...
```

this  sel[] contains like

```
          sel[0]:='col1_name'
          sel[1]:='col5_name'
          sel[2]:='col6_name'
          sel[3]:='col25_name'
```

so first we have to split the array values in separate variable and these variable will be assumed in select statement will be

```
'select'||col1, col5,col6,col25||'from......'
```

Finally want to say briefly I need to pass an array in parameters and have to separate a array values and it will assign to separate variables. these variable will use to select a statement in dynamic manner

Comment: so you create your dynamic statement. what you do with it?.. return what? setof? table? number of rows?

Comment: @VaoTsun i doesn't create any statement or procedure for this i mentioned just for your reference. i need a procedure for this above criteria and will return as cursor. Kindly help me regarding this.

Comment: So, you need something like a [`refcursor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)? http://rextester.com/FMCUW60860 -- Although please don't forget to quote column names with either `format()` or `quote_ident()` to minimize SQL injection possibility.

Comment: @pozs Ya exactly! it will return refcursor

Answer (score 2):

A bare [`refcursor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) can contain any number of columns. Although you'll need a special statement to read from it: [`FETCH ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_my_method(check_in text, sel text[], ref refcursor)
  RETURNS refcursor
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $func$
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || (SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(c), ', ')
                                     FROM   unnest(sel) c) || ' FROM ...';
  RETURN ref;
END;
$func$;

SELECT func_my_method('check_in', ARRAY['col1', 'col2'], 'sample_name');
FETCH ALL IN sample_name;
```

http://rextester.com/ZCZT84224

**Note**: You *could* omit the `refcursor` parameter & `DECLARE` one in your function body. This way PostgreSQL will generate a (non-conflicting) name for the refcursor, which will be returned when calling `SELECT func_my_method(...)`. You'll need that name in the `FETCH ...` statement.

**Update**: If you want to fully qualify (some) columns (i.e. write table name & column too), you'll need either:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_my_method2(check_in text, sel text[], ref refcursor)
  RETURNS refcursor
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $func$
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || (SELECT string_agg((SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(c), '.')
                                                        FROM   unnest(string_to_array(fq, '.')) c), ', ')
                                     FROM   unnest(sel) fq) || ' FROM ...';
  RETURN ref;
END;
$func$;

SELECT func_my_method2('check_in', ARRAY['col1', 'check_in.col2'], 'sample_name2');
FETCH ALL IN sample_name2;
```

(this will split the `sel` parameter into "parts" of the fully qualified name on `.` -- but have a disadvantage: the table & column names cannot contain `.`)

Or:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_my_method3(check_in text, sel text[][], ref refcursor)
  RETURNS refcursor
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $func$
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || (SELECT string_agg((SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(sel[i][j]), '.')
                                                        FROM   generate_subscripts(sel, 2) j), ', ')
                                     FROM   generate_subscripts(sel, 1) i) || ' FROM ...';
  RETURN ref;
END;
$func$;

SELECT func_my_method3('check_in', ARRAY[ARRAY['check_in', 'col1'], ARRAY['check_in', 'col2']], 'sample_name3');
FETCH ALL IN sample_name3;
```

(but this has an uncomfortable consequence: since arrays need to be rectangular, all column sub-arrays need to be the same exact dimensions; so you'll need to provide table name for all of the columns or to neither of them.)

http://rextester.com/JNI24740

Comment: @dineshdanny yes, fully qualified names cannot be used directly with `format()` or `quote_ident()`. If you want to select from only 1 table, just omit them in the parameters & use `'SELECT mm_items.' || (SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(c), ', mm_items.') ...` ...

Comment: @dineshdanny ... if you want to use multiple tables then you either don't use quotation in your function (but then **always** call that function from a trusted source; maybe `REVOKE` some privileges to achieve that) -- or, you'll need to "parse" the `sel` parameter. (f.ex. split on `.`).

Comment: @pozs Can you pls send me an example for this multiple table.

Comment: SELECT func_my_method('CDM', ARRAY['mm_items.id','mm_items.nm_code','um.code']);